# will TBXML Parser be approved by apple?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xml-parsing, tbxml

If anybody has used TBXml parser in iphone application without any memory leak,will it be approved by apple?because it is a third party utility.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a source file and you're compiling it into your project, yes, it should be fine.  Apple disapproves of third party frameworks, which are different from what you're using here.

-- edit --
I have done something very similar but with JSON and ASI and the apps got into the store without any problem.  Make sure that you provide attribution for this source code if their license requires it, however, Apple doesn't seem to check for this at all.

Comment: did you see the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project...it says tbxml is better one in less memory and less fetching time? but you are telling it will be rejected by apple? how can it be true?